# Razor over MVC4 on dotNet 4.5 of VS12 doesn't work with Intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

Did this use to be an issue to someone here too ? I searched SO but could not find any posts that really helped me.

Some told me to press Ctrl+Space after inserting a 'dot', which is not what I would like to get. Razor used to work fine once I tested it with VS10.

[updated] it is Ctrl+Space

Comment: as far as I know ctrl+space is the short cut for intellisense or auto complete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellisense does work in VS2012 with Razor. I've had problems before were visual studio will stop doing Intellisense. Usually a restart of visual studio will fix it for me.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and unchecked the boxes and I restarted many times, but it is still the same

Comment: This question/thread might help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542813/intellisense-in-mvc4-project-not-working-in-vs-2012-professional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542813/intellisense-in-mvc4-project-not-working-in-vs-2012-professional)